# Visual Studio Publish: Copy Embedded Resource

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, publish

I am publishing a web application from Visual Studio 2010 in IIS. The solution structure is depicted below:

[image]

Now everything is fine, except the Log4Net.xml is copied into the bin directory of the published forlder, while Data.xml is copied in right place. So I am manually copying the Log4Net.xml.

Why this is happening? Is there any script I can write for this publishing process?

Comment: If you go to "properties" for the XML file, is "Copy to local" set to true?

Comment: Your title says 'copying an embedded resource'. You shouldn't have the log4net.xml as an embedded resource to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on Log4Net.xml and go to Properties.

Change the `Build Action` from 'Embedded Resource' to 'Content'

Change `Copy to Output Directory` to 'Copy always'.

Answer (score 1):

You can control how the resource is handled by looking at the properties of the file in Visual Studio.  There's a property "Copy to output directory", which will cause it to be sent to the "bin" folder on publish.  There's another property "Build Action", which you can set to compile, resource, embedded resource, etc.  Check those two properties for the file that's getting deployed correctly, and you should be good to go.